# MongoDB "Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0"

Tags: mongodb, mern

I'm following this (https://codingthesmartway.com/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-2/) tutorial, and when I reach the part when I type "mongod" into the terminal, I end up with this holy hot mess in my command line. What's gone wrong?
[image]

Comment: Had the same issue, but I also knew it worked on my computer (it just yielded this error message one day), thus restarting my PC worked. Not really a solution but maybe someone might find it useful here.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not specify a location for the data files, MongoDB will store its data by default in the `\data\db` folder of the current drive `C:`. If the folder does not exist, it will fail with this error. Either create the `C:\data\db` folder or specify a different location for the data files with the `--dbpath` option.

The `TLS 1.0 disabled` warning is not causing any issues. It is just notifying you that TLS 1.0 is disabled by default (TLS 1.0 is considered insecure for encrypted connections), so by default MongoDB only supports TLS 1.1 and newer. This is important only if you're enabling SSL connections to your database.

Comment: Alright, I tried adding that directory. I ran the "mongod" command, and I ended up with a bunch of files being written to that directory. But I still get a hot holy mess of a terminal output. Is there anything else that might be broken?

Comment: If you do not specify a log file location, MongoDB will write all log output to the console where you launch it. So it is normal. If you want to save the logs to a file, there is a `--logpath` option for that.

Comment: I tried using the command "mongod --logpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log". I still see a huge output of logs on my console. Is there something wrong witht the command?

Comment: Not sure what output you're seeing, normally you get some warnings about your system's configuration not being ideal for MongoDB, you can ignore those. The  `--quiet` option disables most output if that is what you want.

Comment: that's probably because your logpath does not exist @Luciancahil. Read the output. Also, where is your `--dbpath` in that command?

Answer (score 2):

After installing MongoDB, setup the environment variable of mongodb.
or make a data/db in your C: drive.
if all these are not woking then install mongodb compass and follow the below steps:

1# In start menu type services and open it

2# look for mongodb and start it manually

3# now to check mongod server is running or not go to c:/prografiles/mongodb/4.4/bin/ (where you install your mongodb compass) and open terminal and type mongo > show dbs command show all the databases.

images links for better understanding:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CLwjXCZ8q6JKwfBXZT9byC_KHmtAjP6E?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome here, if you believe the images are important for the answer, please edit the post and upload them as part of the post rather than provide a link.

Comment: I think it is correct

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my Ubuntu machine. I found the solution by restarting the MongoDB; use the following commands to restart:-

```sh
sudo systemctl stop mongod
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

You can also check it in [How to install MongoDB on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

c:\data\db\ is not found so create it .the same error occurred in  my terminal and it was saying that E:\data\db\ is not found and then I created it in my E drive and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

same huge mess for me,
this command will help.
`./mongod.exe --config ./mongod.cfg --auth`

Answer (score 0):

try to run mongodb with parameter --dbpath /usr/local/mongodb-data if you using mac m1